# Failing to update ssh keys in azure linux vm

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am currently using the "Azure Migrate" service to migrate VMS from GCP to azure. We use centos 7 VMS. I could successfully migrate VM instance in azure and it looks like the status is running. But it's failing to update my ssh key. It throws the below error

"The VM agent is either unavailable or not installed, which may prevent VMAccess from running."

I have checked the VM's agent status and it shows the "not ready" from azure portal.what should i do to update my ssh key ? Or am i missing something ?

Comment: Hello @Sridevi Raman , If the issue is still not resolved then please reach out to Azure Support for Assisted support by going to (Help+Support) and creating a technical support request.

Comment: FYI this should be posted to ServerFault, not Stack Overflow (it's not programming-related).

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshoot the VMagent not ready status:**

- Check the service status of the Azure Linux Agent to make sure it's
  running. The service name will be walinuxagent .
- If the service is running, restart it to resolve the issue. If the
  service is stopped, start it, wait a few minutes, and then check the
  status again.
- Make sure auto-update is enabled. Check the auto-update setting in /etc/waagent.conf.

> Command : AutoUpdate.Enabled=y

- Make sure the VM can connect to the Fabric Controller. Use a tool such as curl to test whether the VM can connect to 168.63.129.16 on ports 80, 443, and 32526. If the VM doesn't connect as expected,check whether outbound communication over ports 80, 443, and 32526 is open in your local firewall on the VM. If this IP address is blocked,the VM agent might display unexpected behavior.

**Troubleshoot VMAccess Extension :**

- Open Azure portal > VM > Settings > Extensions > Extensions
  status and check if the extensions are in provisioning succeeded
  state.
- If not uninstall and then install back the “VMAcess” Extension .

**Reference:**

[VMAccess](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/VMAccess)